# heroku Error R10

Tags: heroku

```
I created a sample app called stock portfolio manager
```

https://github.com/rohanmoitra/foliomanage and deployed it on heroku. But whenever I try to run heroku rake db:migrate it times out and gives the following error.

```
2012-10-22T22:28:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process
 failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2012-10-22T22:28:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-10-22T22:28:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-10-22T22:28:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any help would be deeply appreciated
```

Comment: updated to the latest version of heroku and removed the line gem 'heroku' from the gemfile. Also do a commit to git and then push to heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do migrations on heroku boot. The latter is limited to 60 seconds. Run migrations separately as a rake task. If you really, really want to do this though, you have to work around the boot timeout (https://github.com/dblock/heroku-forward could help).